# Tsql -> filter data 6 months from today, date field in table is YYYYMM

Tags: t-sql, date

I need some help. 
Currently is March 2017.
how do I extract all records 6 months ago from February 2017 until end of this year. the date format in my table is in YYYYMM

Here is my sql statement

```
select columns from budget
where month_number > = DATEADD(MONTH, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

the output I am getting is as below:

```
+------------+-------+--------------+
| month_name | month | month_number |
+------------+-------+--------------+
| January    |     1 |       201601 |
| February   |     2 |       201602 |
| March      |     3 |       201603 |
| April      |     4 |       201604 |
| May        |     5 |       201605 |
| June       |     6 |       201606 |
| July       |     7 |       201607 |
| August     |     8 |       201608 |
| September  |     9 |       201609 |
| October    |    10 |       201610 |
| November   |    11 |       201611 |
| December   |    12 |       201612 |
| January    |     1 |       201701 |
| February   |     2 |       201702 |
| March      |     3 |       201703 |
| April      |     4 |       201704 |
| July       |     7 |       201707 |
| December   |    12 |       201712 |
+------------+-------+--------------+
```

I am not getting the right output. I am still getting data from Jan 2016 onwards. Please help

Thanks

Comment: `how do I extract all records 6 months ago from February 2017 until end of this year` - can you please clarify what *exactly* you're wanting to select...  This doesn't make a lot of sense as written.  Please show some sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please clarify the data types of various fields.  Is `month_number` char, varchar, nvarchar, int, or perhaps something else???

Comment: john got me exactly what I wanted. The month_number is int

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select *
 From  Budget
 Where month_number>= convert(varchar(6),DATEADD(MONTH, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),112) 
 Order By month_number
```

If 2012+

```
Select *
 From  Budget
 Where month_number>=  format(DATEADD(MONTH, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'yyyyMM') 
 Order By month_number
```

Returns

```
month_name  month   month_number
September   9       201609
October     10      201610
November    11      201611
December    12      201612
January     1       201701
February    2       201702
March       3       201703
April       4       201704
July        7       201707
December    12      201712
```

Comment: John, this works great. Please explain this to me for my understanding.

Comment: @user396123 we just convert your CURRENT_TIMESTAMP into a INTEGER yyyymm to test against your month_number field For example, Select cast(convert(varchar(6),DATEADD(MONTH, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),112) as int)  returns 201609

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively ..

```
declare @budget table (month_Number int)

insert @budget (month_number)
select 201601
union all
select 201602
union all
select 201702
union all
select 201705
union all
select 201709


select * from @budget
where month_number >= (YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) * 100) +  MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));
```